# Code is working locally but not on Heroku

Tags: heroku, bots, messenger

I am testing Facebook Messenger bot. Part of the code with core functionality:

```
const schedule = require('node-schedule');

app.post('/webhook/', function(req, res) {
    let messaging_events = req.body.entry[0].messaging
    var j = schedule.scheduleJob('10 * * * * *', function(){
        for (let i = 0; i < messaging_events.length; i++) {
        let event = messaging_events[i]
        let sender = event.sender.id
        if (event.message && event.message.text) {
            let text = event.message.text
            sendText(sender, "Text echo: " + text.substring(0, 100))
        }
    }
    res.sendStatus(200)
    })  
})
```

It should reply the same message that is sent to the bot every minute (when the clock crosses 10 seconds - 2:46:10 PM, 2:47:10 PM, etc.)

If I try similar code locally, it works. It does not on Heroku. It behaves irregularly - sometimes it replies the message 2 to 4 times at once and then crashes, sometimes it does not reply anything at all. Here is the Heroku log:

```
    2018-03-19T13:48:43.574712+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2018-03-19T13:48:43.575153+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2018-03-19T13:48:45.854373+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2018-03-19T13:48:48.046370+00:00 app[web.1]: running: port
2018-03-19T13:48:48.550571+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-03-19T13:49:10.035608+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/webhook/" host=dry-badlands-96368.herokuapp.com request_id=89a76e53-663d-4086-8457-64c0f26be8c7 fwd="31.13.113.20" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=11963ms status=200 bytes=201 protocol=https
2018-03-19T13:49:10.046345+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/webhook/" host=dry-badlands-96368.herokuapp.com request_id=0da8c7a9-4d5f-45bc-8797-54f608968581 fwd="31.13.105.114" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=20401ms status=200 bytes=201 protocol=https

2018-03-19T13:49:41.297748+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/webhook/" host=dry-badlands-96368.herokuapp.com request_id=cd1568a1-68c3-455f-872e-260f8023d925 fwd="31.13.113.170" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30002ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2018-03-19T13:49:41.747709+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/webhook/" host=dry-badlands-96368.herokuapp.com request_id=32947747-1c2b-475c-a2b8-46477e13c4a2 fwd="31.13.114.116" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2018-03-19T13:50:10.059682+00:00 app[web.1]: _http_outgoing.js:491
2018-03-19T13:50:10.059738+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
2018-03-19T13:50:10.059740+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2018-03-19T13:50:10.059742+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-03-19T13:50:10.059744+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
2018-03-19T13:50:10.059745+00:00 app[web.1]:     at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:491:11)
2018-03-19T13:50:10.059747+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:498:3)
2018-03-19T13:50:10.059748+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ServerResponse.header (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:767:10)
2018-03-19T13:50:10.059750+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ServerResponse.contentType (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:595:15)
2018-03-19T13:50:10.059752+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ServerResponse.sendStatus (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:357:8)
2018-03-19T13:50:10.059753+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Job.job (/app/index.js:46:9)
2018-03-19T13:50:10.059755+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Job.invoke (/app/node_modules/node-schedule/lib/schedule.js:173:10)
2018-03-19T13:50:10.059756+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/node-schedule/lib/schedule.js:543:11
2018-03-19T13:50:10.059758+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Timeout._onTimeout (/app/node_modules/node-schedule/lib/schedule.js:501:7)
2018-03-19T13:50:10.059759+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ontimeout (timers.js:482:11)
2018-03-19T13:50:10.130605+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-03-19T13:50:10.241686+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Does anyone have any idea why is this happening? Maybe Heroku is not suited for this?

Thank you for all suggestions.